# Edit context menu icon in Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, nemo

I have`Cinnamon` on my Ubuntu with custom theme. Now I would like to customise context menu shown upon right click on desktop. In my case there is very large icon for `Open as root` action, which I'd like to fix.

[image]